# Не могу поднять проект на ZendFramework

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework

Не могу поднять проект после "смерти сервака"
Вылетает ошибка через WEB (You don't have permission to access /php-bin/php/index.php on this server.)

В логах (AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/php-bin-isp-php70/voishunter/php)

БД на Postgres, подключена
Уже замучился и не знаю в чем проблема...

Прилагаю vhost

```
<VirtualHost 188.165.192.38:80 [2001:41d0:2:8926::]:80>
ServerName on-the-go.eu
ServerAlias www.on-the-go.eu
DocumentRoot /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
ServerAdmin webmaster@on-the-go.eu
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
AddDefaultCharset off
SuexecUserGroup voishunter voishunter
CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/on-the-go.eu.access.log combined
ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/on-the-go.eu.error.log
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
ScriptAlias /php-bin/ /home/php-bin-isp-php70/voishunter/
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php-bin/php
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 188.165.192.38:443 [2001:41d0:2:8926::]:443>
ServerName on-the-go.eu
ServerAlias www.on-the-go.eu
DocumentRoot /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
ServerAdmin webmaster@on-the-go.eu
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
AddDefaultCharset off
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/on-the-go.eu.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/on-the-go.eu.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/var/www/httpd-cert/voishunter/on-the-go.eu.ca"
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH 
SuexecUserGroup voishunter voishunter
CustomLog /home/httpd-logs/on-the-go.eu.access.log combined
ErrorLog /home/httpd-logs/on-the-go.eu.error.log
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
ScriptAlias /php-bin/ /home/php-bin-isp-php70/voishunter/
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /php-bin/php
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/public>
Options +Includes -ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: ou don't have permission to access  - у вас нет доступа к index.php проверьте права

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev  Да вот дело в том, что есть права

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev Поправил, info отобразилось, но когда вернул старый index.php в логах полезло следующие

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.' in /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/init_autoloader.php:51\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/public/index.php(21): require()\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /home/voishunter/data/www/on-the-go.eu/init_autoloader.php on line 51

Comment: Композером загрузите все зависимости, включая ZF2